# trouble joining tables in code first entity framework MVC c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hi I have 2 questions both related. First I a having trouble setting up code first EF tables that link.  I have a product model, productimage model and category model as so

```
 public class Product
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string SKU { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string DescriptionShort { get; set; }


        public decimal Weight { get; set; }
        public string Size { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int WebStatus { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public decimal SalePrice { get; set; }
        public DateTime SaleDateExpires { get; set; }
        public Boolean FeaturedProduct { get; set; }
        public Boolean NewProduct { get; set; }
        public Boolean TopRated { get; set; }
        public Boolean BestSellers { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string ImageName { get; set; }
        public string ImageExtension { get; set; }

        public Category Category { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ProductImage> ProductImage { get; set; }   
    }   

 public class ProductImage
        {        
            public int ProductImageID { get; set; }
            public int ProductID { get; set; }
            public string ImageType { get; set; }
            public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
            public string ImageName { get; set; }

            public Product Product { get; set; }      
        }

public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is model passed from the controller code

```
var products = _context.Products.Include(c => c.Category).Include(i => i.ProductImage);
```

But I can only get the products and the category.   I cant figure out how to have access to the productimage fields.

Question 1.  How can I display the products, category and all images associated with that product from the productimage model.

My view is using

```
@model IEnumerable<shop.Models.Product>
```

Since I don't need to edit any data it's all for view purposes. I don't get intelisense or access to the productimage model.

I have tried this

```
<img class="full-width img-responsive" src="@product.ProductImage.>
```

but it doesn't work.  Is this because it is a collection and I have to loop thru the data some how?

Question 2.  Once I get that working, I want to display different products in different sections.  ex ( new products,  sale products , popular products) in different areas of the same page.  What is the best way and how do I do this.
My guess is different viewmodels, combined viewmodels, or one model and then looping thru the data with if statements.

Please give an example 
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would pluralize to ProductImages - much clearer that it is a collection. Next, since it is a collection you would typically use a grid or table to display the data.

As for grouping by type, you could just use some LINQ to filter.

Here is a bootstrap styled example:

```
<h2>New Products</h2>
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th class="col-md-4">Product Name</th>
        <th class="col-md-4">SKU</th>
        <th class="col-md-4">Description</th>
    </tr>
    // filter just the new products. could add an `if` to check if empty
    @foreach (var product in Model.Products.Where(pi => pi.NewProduct))
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => product.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => product.SKU)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => product.Description)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>   // Add another row (or column) for image(s)
            <table>
                // header here
                // loop thru multiple images for this product
                @foreach (var image in product.ProductImages)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>image.Name</td>
                        // other columns
                    </tr>
                }
            <table>

        </tr>

    }

</table>

// Repeat for other sections.


@foreach (var product in Model.Where(pi => pi.FeaturedProduct == true))
            {
                foreach (var image in product.ProductImage.Where(it => it.ImageType == "Thumb"))
                {
                    <img class="full-width img-responsive" src="@image.ImageUrl" >

            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  So am I safe to assume that the models ( except for the pluralization) and controller where all correctly defined.

Comment: And it's just that since it is a collection I have to loop thru the data as suggested?

Comment: Your entity models look fine. Long term you might want to research the ViewModel pattern where you map your entity models to what you need in your views. And, yes, since you have a collection of images and if you want to show more than 1 you need to loop. Another option would be to just show 1, for example `Model.ProductImages.FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Hi steve  I understand the  code  " @foreach (var image in Model.ProductImages.Where(pi => pi.ImageType == "New"))
    {"  for filtering the data.  But I think i did not do a good job explaining.  I do want to do a filter for for loop but I want to do the filter on the Product model.  On the Field of "Featured Product", "New Product", "Sale Product" and then do the loop of the images in the ProductImages model.  How do I do that

Comment: ImageType in productImages would be "Thumbnail", "Main", "Slider"  and I want to just pick the ProductImage-ImageType (can be mulitple images) for each Product-(New Product or Featured Product or Sale Product)

Comment: OK, see edit. You would need nested tables to do that. There are other ways with grids like Kendo.

Comment: Ok great, I just figured that out. I added the code to your edit that i used

Answer (score 0):

With help from Steve this is the code I ended up using that worked.

```
@foreach (var product in Model.Where(pi => pi.FeaturedProduct == true))
            {
                foreach (var image in product.ProductImage.Where(it => it.ImageType == "Thumb"))
                {
                    <img class="full-width img-responsive" src="@image.ImageUrl" >

                }
```